# Total Newbie stuck while trying to load Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

bear with me but:  I'm trying to download Ubuntu to dual-boot with XP. Think of me as your Grandad!  Have used Wubi from Canonical and loaded to my 'downloads' folder. Next step is to 'Verify' by running 'Echo etc.' - question is How?.  Have placed file in 'Downloads' and run via CMD but all I get is 'shasum is not recognized as an internal or external command etc. So how do I 'run' it plse?

Again - be gentle and use Olde English.

Saturday now - I take it that nobody can talk me through the process of running the verifier then?

The 'How do I install Ubuntu' thread is of no use at all as it doesn't even mention verifying the downloaded file  (section 2) - let alone how.

Comment: WUBI has been deprecated and unmaintained for many years. Seems an unwise choice.

Comment: Welcome! Try creating your bootable USB with [rufus](https://rufus.ie)

Comment: Point me to another dual-boot offering and I'll have another go.  But prefer not to use USB/DVD but load direct from hdisk.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. To install Ubuntu you have to create a bootable USB, you can't install it "from disk".

Comment: OK - according to Canonical - I can, but obviously not as easy as they say.  By the way - thanks for taking this up .  Am I taking it correctly then- create a dvd , press F10 on startup, select DVD and away..

Comment: The bootable usb/dvd is just fot installing Ubuntu on your hard drive. It is the easiest way to install Ubuntu.How old is your computer ? The Ubuntu default desktop might not be suitable with the performances of your computer.

Comment: very old - amd 64 1,8 ghz proc. loads of disk space, runs xp3 ok but trying to move to Linux as everybody says its possible

Comment: currently trying to load ubuntu 19.10 which is supposed to work ok on this box

Comment: Have run CPUID - CPU Z which says 64 bit ok

Comment: Download the ISO file for a version of your choice at https://ubuntu.com/download or a 'flavour' w/ a different Desktop Environment, downloaded from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file you use to create a LiveDVD should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 before making the LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0 . Once you make a LiveDVD, install it following https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

Comment: OK - I'll give all that a try - prob see you all on Saturday then.  Many thanks all...

Comment: Ubuntu is NOT designed to run on very old hardware: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements. Lighter flavors (like Xubuntu or Lubuntu) might be a better match for your hardware's capabilities.

Comment: The Lubuntu flavour would be more suitable for your computer.

Comment: I'll check them all out .. Ta

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: OK I'll read it all but if it ends up with 'run the verifier to check that the download is kosher'  I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
  For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: Brill, haven't read/absorbed it all yet but seems to be what I need (the actual physical things I need to do.  Many thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments have noted, Wubi is really no longer in use.  Instead, you should consider downloading a recent Ubuntu ISO file from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop.  When you reach the actual download page, you will see a link to "Verify your download".  This will display the SHA256 checksum for the downloaded ISO file.  Since you are using Windows, a simple way to verify the downloaded file is to use the MD5 & SHA Checksum Utility (https://raylin.wordpress.com/downloads/md5-sha-1-checksum-utility/).  Running this program displays a window that lets you browse to the location of the downloaded ISO file, copy the SHA256 checksum obtained above, and automatically verify the latter against the checksum generated for the downloaded file.

Comment: OK, checksum now run fine - many thanks CentaurusA. and to all that replied, no doubt it was all hidden away somewhere in all the snow I've read over the past week but got lost in the storm.  Merry Christmas all...  Subject closed..